# Adding complex object to SOAP Response

Tags: object, response, android-ksoap2, serializable, envelope

I sent my complex objects to the Request like :
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19289123/can-not-pass-serialized-object-from-android-to-c-sharp-web-service)
now I want to getting complex objects from the Response.
The following is a sample SOAP 1.1 response :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <soap:Body>
        <CommitReceiptionAgentResponse xmlns="http://mywebService.ir/">
          <CommitReceiptionAgentResult Exc="string">
            <Errors>
              <string>string</string>
              <string>string</string>
            </Errors>
            <CST>dateTime</CST>              
          </CommitReceiptionAgentResult>
        </CommitReceiptionAgentResponse>
      </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

I created CommitReceiptionAgentResponse Class :

```
public class CommitReceiptionAgentResponse implements KvmSerializable {
    @Element(name = "CommitReceiptionAgentResult")
    CommitReceiptionAgentResult commitReceiptionAgentResult;
.
.
.
}
```

and I created CommitReceiptionAgentResult Class too :

```
    public class CommitReceiptionAgentResult extends Vector<String> implements KvmSerializable {
            @ElementList(name = "Errors")
            public Errors errors;

            @Attribute(name = "Exc", required = false)    
            public String InternalServiceException;

               @Element(name = "CST", required = false)
               public Date CommitStartTime;
.
    .
    .
    }
```

that getProperty() method of CommitReceiptionAgentResult class defined as blew :

```
@Override
    public Object getProperty(int arg0) {
        switch (arg0) {
        case 0:
            Errors errorList =  getErrors();
            SoapObject erlistObject = new SoapObject(
                    ServiceUtil.WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE, "errorList");
                 try{
            if (errorList.size() > 0) {
                for (String error : errorList) {
                    SoapObject erObject = new SoapObject(
                        ServiceUtil.WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE, "Errors");

                        PropertyInfo info = new PropertyInfo();
                        errorList.getPropertyInfo(0, null, info);
                        erObject.addProperty(info.name,
                                errorList.getProperty(0));

                    erlistObject.addSoapObject(erObject);
                }
            }       
                  }catch (Exception e) {    
                  }
            return erlistObject;                    
        case 1:
            return getInternalServiceException();
        case 2:
            return getCommitStartTime();        
        }
        return null;
    }               
        @Element(name = "CST", required = false)
        public Date CommitStartTime;        

}
```

and I create Errors class like this :

```
   public class Errors extends Vector<String> implements KvmSerializable{   
    @Override
    public Object getProperty(int arg0) {
            return this.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public int getPropertyCount() {
            return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public void getPropertyInfo(int arg0, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo arg2) {
            arg2.name = "string";
            arg2.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
    }

    @Override
    public void setProperty(int arg0, Object arg1) {
            this.add(arg1.toString());
    }
}
```

When I define soap Objects and envelope according to 
[this link](http://www.blackberry-forum.de/cgi-bin/YaBB.pl?num=1260616413)
and 
[this](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/CodingTipsAndTricks#sending/receiving_array_of_complex_types_or_primitives)
, **envelope.getResponse() is null** :

```
    final SoapObject response1 = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,
                        "CommitReceiptionAgentResponse");

    response1.addProperty("CommitReceiptionAgentResult",
                        new CommitReceiptionAgentResult());

    final SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                        SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.bodyOut = request;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(response1);                                
    envelope.addMapping(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,
                        "CommitReceiptionAgentResponse",
                        new CommitReceiptionAgentResponse().getClass());
    envelope.addMapping(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,
                        "CommitReceiptionAgentResult",
                        new CommitReceiptionAgentResult().getClass());
    envelope.addMapping(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE, "Errors",
                        new Errors().getClass());
    HttpTransportSE httpTransport1 = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
    try {

        httpTransport1.debug = true;
        httpTransport1.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
                    httpTransport1.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); // in/out
         SoapObject response = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.getResponse();
}catch(exception){}
```

I searched a lots, but could not find the problem. 
I want to know my implementation of classes and addMAppings Is 'true'?! If it is wrong what is the currect answer.
I will be appreciate if any one help me.
Thanks in advance

Excuse me for my english.

Comment: you have to provide more details. in your code you are using "CommitReceiptionAgentResponse" as methodName, which usually should be "CommitReceiptionAgent" not response. Do you have a WSDL? if yes, search for a "message" tag with "CommitReceiptionAgent" on it, and provide it here so we can assist you better. If you have an online link for the WSDL its even better, paste it here

Comment: you changed it to what? did it fix your problem?

Comment: I changed methodName  to CommitReceiptionAgent but did not fix my problem. message tag with CommitReceiptionAgent is :     <wsdl:message name="CommitReceiptionAgentSoapIn"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:CommitReceiptionAgent"/></wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="CommitReceiptionAgentSoapOut"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:CommitReceiptionAgentResponse"/></wsdl:message>